# M2M between two different apps

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have two models in separate apps:

```
# Groups app
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    admin = models.ManyToManyField('UserProfile')

# UserProfile app
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
```

In other words, a user may belong to several groups (User M2M to Groups), and also a group may have one or more administratrators (Group M2M to Users). I am having trouble with doing a `syncdb` here because of this. What would be the best way to proceed here? Should I 1) combine `Groups` into the `UserProfile` app? or 2) user `ALTER TABLE` statements after the fact to make one of the M2M links? or 3) Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    admin = models.ManyToManyField('userprofile.UserProfile')
```